# Who ends up with control of a Recombublated Shadow-Mad minion?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm thinking about adding a Recombobulator or two to my Priest deck, but I'd need to craft them first, so I was wondering about the effectiveness of this specific interaction.

Comment: Totally recommend it. You can shadow madness the minion, trade with it to 1 health, then recomb it to a full minion and keep it. It's a lot of value if you can use it properly.

Comment: Add a Shrinkmeister to shadow an ysera, free 9 mana minion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The player recombulating the minion gets to keep it, as shown in [Trolldens latest video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewFb10R_t5E). 
In the first clip, the priest uses Shadow Madness on a minion and recombulates it, keeping the changed minion.